# My form resolution revert back to my laptop native resolution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, merge-conflict-resolution

I created some forms but when I debugged them, it come out with different resolution forms. Whenever I click Enter button, it will revert back to my laptop original resolution. My laptop screen is 1920 x 1080 and the form resolution is 1366 x 768. And these are the pictures.

[image: before press enter]

[image: after press enter]

[same case on my reportviewer as well][3]

[after that these became messy][4]

appreciate if someone can give some suggestion or advice

Comment: What do you mean _"it will revert back to my laptop original resolution"_. Does your application change the screen resolution? You need to show us your code, we can't help you based on a simple description of the problem. Also, I see no difference whatsoever in your two images.

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with your project.  Looks like you have some kind of utility installed on your machine that changes the window chrome.  Giving it a blue title bar, the window fell back to the normal Win10 chrome.  The message box window has the wrong chrome again.  Maybe it behaves better when you [declare your app to be dpiAware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e/13228495?s=1|0.0000#13228495), but uninstalling it ought to be pretty high on the priority list.

Comment: @visual vincent My problem is the form resolution does not change until i hit enter button. When i debug it, the form resolution was about like the picture above. Until I hit enter button, the form became another resolution and size. .